# Can a passenger in transit at Heathrow get to a post office?

Tags: transit, lhr, mail, services

I am flying to heathrow in transit to the USA. Can I go to the post office to post a gift to my friend? Is it possible for someone in transit to use the post office service? Could I buy a gift to send to my friend's home by courier or post?

Comment: We need to know if you require a Visa to enter the UK or not. The Post Office at Heathrow is "landside" (before the outbound security checks) in Terminal 3. To gain access to the Post Office you would need to enter the UK. To do this you'd also need to factor in the time you'd need to clear inbound Immigration, check in to your onward connecting flight if not already done and then go through the outbound security checks. It might be easier to mail the item direct to your friend from your home country/country of departure.

Comment: It is rather surprising that this is not common and easy.  I would have thought that an air side post office would do good business with bored transit passengers.

Answer (score 8):

You can purchase stamps and deposit letters in postboxes after security in each terminal (the online terminal map does not appear to say where exactly these are), so as long as your gift fits into the post box and you are able to buy enough stamps, then it is probably possible to send the item.

If you must use an actual post office, you would need to be [landside at Terminal 3](https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/postal-services) to use the post office at the airport, requiring you to pass immigration during your transit. If you have time and no visa restrictions, the airport's post office is open from 0730 to 1730 on weekdays, from 0900 to 1730 on Saturdays and 0900 to 1300 on Sundays.